# Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99"

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have run into an issue. Whenever I run my test class it is showing the following error:

```
Testsuite: com.lo.test.selenium.AssignCampaignTestCase
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 46.991 sec
------------- Standard Error -----------------
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous4942696774897131989webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG addons.manager: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: /tmp/anonymous4942696774897131989webdriver-profile/extensions/webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found

        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:109)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:245)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:109)
```

My test class:

```
package com.lo.test.selenium; 

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store; 
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class MyExampleTestCase {

    private static ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("global-messages");

    static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  //Make it static in order to make one instance of this class(helps to avoid opening of 2 browsers at once)

    @Test
    public void campaignEmailTestCase() throws InterruptedException { 
        MyExampleTestCase emTesObj = new MyExampleTestCase ();  
        String fName = "test LO";
        Integer LeadId = 570903;
        String campaignName = "2Get"; 
        String SubjName = "Welcome"; //NOTE: No problem, Type without double quotes. It will work for you 

        emTesObj.doLogin(); 
        emTesObj.goToLeadsListPage();
        emTesObj.searchByFirstName(fName); //without this also,it will work but gives you the correct navigation on UI
        emTesObj.waitBeforePageLoads(LeadId.toString()); //pass the Id attribute which you aspect to see after the page is loaded
        emTesObj.assignCampaign(LeadId, campaignName);  
        emTesObj.readRecentEmail(SubjName);  
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I tried the code below but it still is showing the same error after executing this code and [also showed some error with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeS4j.jpg)

```
Xvfb :21 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -extension RANDR &
```

Looks like this code did not run properly. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: What version of FF and Selenium are you using?

Comment: Just for the record: My problem were no installed fonts. Welcome to the club if `fc-match` has no output.

Comment: @Matthias i also solved already, by installing fonts

Comment: What version your using?

Comment: @batman forget now. i solve it that time by doing something , I think latest selenium i was using

Answer (score 0):

Referring to my last comment, the log message `"RANDR" missing on display ":99"` is often not a problem. Check if you have installed any fonts, running `fc-match`. Otherwise, your Firefox won't start and therefore the WebDriver won't be able to connect.

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
```

Comment: @i tried this installing the things which you are pointing but still could not ..

Answer (score 0):

create a bash script file and put the following code. Run this file before running test.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
##script to install the necessary dependency for headless firefox browser
remove_Xvfb (){
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep [X]vfb | awk '{print $2}')
}
remove_screenLock (){
Xvfb :3000 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &
file="/tmp/.X3000-lock"
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "Screen Exits..removing it and installing it again"
    sudo rm -rf "$file"
    export DISPLAY=:3000
else
    echo "Screen Does not Exists....Creating one"
    export DISPLAY=:3000
fi
}
yum install -y xdg-utils xorg-x11-server-Xvfb fontconfig freetype freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libstdc++ Xvfb firefox
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
running=`ps ax | grep -v grep | grep Xvfb | wc -l`
if [ $running -gt 0 ]; then
    echo " Xvfb is running, removing it"
    remove_Xvfb
    remove_screenLock
else
    remove_screenLock
fi
```

This will create a virtual display for your UI bases test cases with firefox browser.